# Oracle Advanced Queue - RabbitMQ integration

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, integration, amqp, advanced-queuing

In some of our projects, the messages will be consumed from Oracle Advanced Queue and will be published to RabbitMQ.

How can I integrate Oracle Advanced Queue with RabbitMQ?

Comment: Integration ? Take a look at Apache Camel  Classic use case.

Answer (score 2):

My answer if far from complete but it might help someone.
Some time ago while i was searching about the integration of oracle with rabbitMQ i found this in github.

https://github.com/pmq/rabbitmq-oracle-stored-procedures

I modified the code for my needs and it worked fine (oracle 12.1.0.1.0 ). Using an oracle trigger i managed to send messages to a rabbitMQ queue after CRUD operations. I am very, very sorry i don't have the code but github is there with the original code. I made minor modifications in this github code and worked fine. I remember i created and loaded in oracle some stored procedures in java (like those in the github repository i mentioned) and used them to communicate with rabbitMQ. I also loaded in oracle necessary rabbitMQ libraries (jars). This was done using loadjava tool. My messages where in json format.

I would be very happy if this extremely incomplete answer helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very wide. Writing a program that reads rabbit queues and copies them to Oracle queues is straight forward in multiple languages, at least in Java.

You can get help from integration suites like Mule ESB and Apache Camel to get all boiler plate code setup for you.

If you want a more specific answer you better rephrase the question to narrow the scope a bit.

Comment: Using a third integration tool to connect two integration tools does not seem to me as the right way.

Comment: Message queues are not really "integration tools", but messages queues - a transport mechanism often used to support integrations. Apache Camel is pretty much made to support this and similar scenarios and a very easy way to solve the problem. But you could of course create a basic program in whatever language and deal with all error handling and transaction management boilerplate code yourself. Sometimes you might need to catch a taxi to transfer from a train to an airplane, nothing wrong with that, right?

Comment: I agree with you Apache Camel could be a quick way in case the pushing/pulling application would be Java based and wouldn't use JMS/AQMP yet. Mule ESB seems to me an overhead unless you need to integrate more applications. Regarding the taxi, sometimes it's better to look at map to find out you can walk before calling a taxi. And that was actually my point, adding another component/framework has its consequences, especially for maintenance. Anyway, I consider your aswer as helpful as long as the question isn't specific enough.